# How to share a variable between two Python classes?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am not an experienced programmer so please keep that in mind.
I have a made an application with Tkinter, it's called a dice rolling simulator.
The code contains three classes:

1. The login screen (class 1)
2. The privacy terms (class 2) (subclass class 1)
3. The game-screen (class 3)

So basically the players have to read the privacy terms and press the button <kbd>OK</kbd>, to acknowledge that they have read privacy terms.
I am trying to make a realistic game.
They cannot play the game until they have read the privacy terms.

My question: How can I pass a variable from class 2 to class 1?

In class 1 I have declared a variable `start_game = False` and in class 2 if the user has read the terms than I change the variable to `True`.

How can I pass the adjusted variable back to class 1 so that the users can play start the game.

If they haven't read the terms and they try to start the game than a error message pops up.

I hope I have made it clear to you.

```
        def Inlogsystem(self):
            if self.startgame == True:

                    user1 = (self.Username1.get())
                    user2 = (self.Username2.get())

                    if user1 != " " and user1 != "" and user2 != " " and user2 != "" and user1 != user2:
                            self.Dobbel2scherm()


                    elif user1 == "" or user1 == " ":
                            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Gebruikersnamen", "De gebruikersnaam van Speler 1 is leeg")
                            self.txtuser.focus_set()

                    elif user2 == "" or user2 == " ":
                            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Gebruikersnamen", "De gebruikersnaam van Speler 2 is leeg")
                            self.txtuser2.focus_set()       

                    elif user1 == user2:
                            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Gebruikersnamen", "De gebruikersnamen mogen niet gelijk aan elkaar zijn")

            else:
                    print('Je hebt de algemene voorwaarden nog niet gelezen')


class Algemene_voorwaarden(Dobbelsteeninlog):
    def __init__(self, window,):

            #---------Window-----------------------
            self.window = window
            self.window.title("Algemene voorwaarden")
            self.window.geometry("450x450+0+0")
            self.window.config(bg="gray24")

            self.Algvoorwaarden = LabelFrame(self.window, width = 450, height= 450, bd=20,
                                          font=('Times New Roman', 10,'bold'),bg="gray24", fg="Paleturquoise3")

            self.Algvoorwaarden.grid(row=0,column=0)

            self.AlgvoorLbl = Label(self.Algvoorwaarden, text='Algemene voorwaarden', font=('Times New Roman', 30,'bold'),bg="gray24", fg="Paleturquoise3")
            self.AlgvoorLbl.grid(row=0,column=0)

            self.AlgvoorwaardTxt = Text(self.window, font=('Times New Roman', 15,'bold'),bg="gray24", height=13, width=30, fg="Paleturquoise3")
            text = 'Algemene voorwaarden. De tering voor je, je krijgt niks vuile hond. Stuur maar een mail naar Alberto Stegeman. Je moet de voorwaarden lezen voordat je kan spelen.'

            self.AlgvoorwaardTxt.insert('1.0',text + '\n')

            self.fontalg = font.Font(self.AlgvoorwaardTxt, self.AlgvoorwaardTxt.cget("font"))
            self.fontalg.configure(underline=True)
            self.AlgvoorwaardTxt.configure(font=self.fontalg)

            self.AlgvoorwaardTxt.grid(row=1, column=0)

            self.AlgBtn = Button(self.window, text='OK',font=('Times New Roman', 10),command= self.start_game_alg)
            self.AlgBtn.grid(row=2,column=0)

    def start_game_alg(self):

            self.startgame = True
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you'd paste some minimal example of your code. Your question is very general.

Comment: `Class1.start_game = True`? Maybe share some relevant code...

Comment: @iScripters i have updated my code . the class 'Algemene_voorwaarden(Dobbelsteeninlog) is the 2nd sub-class.
The 2nd class contains the function that will start the game.

Answer (score 0):

If class 2 is subclass of class 1, then an object of class 2 inherits all members of class 1 and will have therefore access to them over the `self` keyword. Example:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        start_game = False

class Class2(Class1):
    def show_terms(self):
        self.start_game = True

class2_obj = Class2()
class2_obj.show_terms()
print(class2_obj.start_game)
```

However, I am not sure if you really need to make class 2 a subclass of class1, I assume you just want to make the two classes communicate and for that you don't need inheritance. What you need is an association between the two classes, so that two objects of these classes can communicate with each others. Have a look at this example:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_game = False
        self.terms_accepted = False

    def set_terms_accepted(self, terms_accepted):
        self.terms_accepted = terms_accepted

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        terms_accepted = False

    def show_terms(self, class1_obj):
        self.terms_accepted = self.get_user_answer()
        class1_obj.set_terms_accepted(self.terms_accepted)

    def get_user_answer(self):
        # Here you add the code that gets the answer from the user
        return True 

class2_obj = Class2()
class1_obj = Class1()
print(f"Before showing terms: {class1_obj.terms_accepted}")
class2_obj.show_terms(class1_obj)
print(f"After showing terms: {class1_obj.terms_accepted}")
```

Result of the above code:

```
Before showing terms: False
After showing terms: True
```

Comment: thank you. i will try this out, have you seen my code?

Comment: can you maybe help me with my code?, it is still not fixed.

Comment: Yes, but you need to post your code here, or post a minimal code that is big enough so that I can understand what it should do. The code you posted above is not enough for understanding how it works (or how it is supposed to work). Also, there is another language that I can't read!

Comment: alright i will update my code also i will change the language.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help:

```
someVariable = "this is test"
print(someVariable)

class someClass:
   global someVariable
   print(someVariable)
   someVariable = "some other test"
   print(someVariable)
```

Output:

```
this is test
this is test
some other test
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).